# what and how is the dissembler function used for in python?

Tags: python

I just ran across the dissembler function in python. But i couldn't make out what it means. Can anyone explain the working and use, based on the results of the factorial function (based on recursion and loop)

The recursive code and the corresponding dis code:

```
>>> def fact(n):
...     if n==1:
...             return 1
...     return n*fact(n-1)
... 
>>> dis.dis(fact)
2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
          3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
          6 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
          9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       16
3          12 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
         15 RETURN_VALUE        
4     >>   16 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
         19 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (fact)
         22 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
         25 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
         28 BINARY_SUBTRACT     
         29 CALL_FUNCTION            1
         32 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
         33 RETURN_VALUE
```

And the factorial function using loop gives the following result:

```
def factor(n):
...     f=1
...     while n>1:
...             f*=n
...             n-=1
... 
>>> dis.dis(factor)
2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
          3 STORE_FAST               1 (f)

3           6 SETUP_LOOP              36 (to 45)
    >>    9 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
         12 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
         15 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
         18 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       44

4          21 LOAD_FAST                1 (f)
         24 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
         27 INPLACE_MULTIPLY    
         28 STORE_FAST               1 (f)

5          31 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
         34 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
         37 INPLACE_SUBTRACT    
         38 STORE_FAST               0 (n)
         41 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            9
    >>   44 POP_BLOCK           
    >>   45 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
         48 RETURN_VALUE
```

Can anyone tell me how to determine which one is faster?

Comment: When you measure each, which one tends to execute in less time?

Comment: I don't mean to say that at all.

Comment: Can you please explain your point in an answer?

Comment: Refer to @BurhanKhalid's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To measure how fast something is running, use the [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module, which comes with Python.

The `dis` module is used to get some idea of what the bytecode *may* look like; and its very specific to cpython.

One use of it is to see what, when and how storage is assigned for variables in a loop or method.  However, this is a specialized module that is not normally used for efficiency calculations; use `timeit` to figure out how fast something is, and then `dis` to get an understanding of what is going on under the hood - to arrive at a possible *why*.

Answer (score 6):

It's impossible to determine which one will be faster simply by looking at the bytecode; each VM has a different cost associated with each opcode and so runtimes can vary widely.

Comment: so what is this function used for?

Comment: It's not really "used" for anything. It can be used to compare steps required for different algorithms, but that's not a guarantee of performance.

Comment: There can also be huge variations due to how much fits in the CPU cache, etc. So the whole platform needs to be considered when tuning

Answer (score 0):

The `dis.dis()` function disassembles a function into its bytecode interpretation.

**Timing**

As stated by Ignacio, the pure length of the bytecode does not accurately represent the running time due to differences in how python interpreters actually run opcode and the [timeit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module would be what you want to use there.

**Actual Purpose**

There are several uses of this function, but they are not things that most people would end up doing. You can look at the output to help *as part of the process* of optimizing or debugging speed issues. It would also likely prove useful in working directly on the python interpreter, or writing your own. You can look at the documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) to see a full list of the opcodes (though, just as that page will state, it's perfectly likely to change between versions of python).

Overall, this is not something you'd really use much in a production application (unless your application is a python disassembler!) but when you really, *really* need to optimize your code and debug at the lowest level, this is where the function would come in handy.